# How to show traffic route in listview in android map?

Tags: java, android

I'm create map use Google API's  know I'm interested to show the routes in he `listview` in android map how I'm implement this please kindly tell us every one?

Comment: im implementing in map to show traffic on the map show in listview im click on listview show the traffic route?

Comment: im implement the set route and desigination when set route show different routes with traffic status in the listview ??

Answer (score 0):

You want to enable the traffic highlight in map so use this line in onMapReady() methord

```
googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
```

this will help you , it help me.

Comment: thanks for feedback but i show the traffic status in the list is it possible?